# unable to acess any files in _layout

Tags: 2007, mapped-folder

I have numerous js css, and custom pages deployed to the _layouts folder of my SharePoint 2007 farm. These are used by numerous farm wide solutions. Today, something has gone wrong with the permissions on the _layout folder on the one server and we are getting "http 404 not found" errors when trying to access these files.

I have compared the security on this server to the other servers in the farm and they are the same. Has anyone had this before?

Comment: have an example of the string you are using to get them?

Comment: it is a generated url from code, I have a visual studio solution with a mapped _layouts folder. so the url is http://mysite/_layouts/somefolder/myfile.aspx.

even when registering a script block in a custom web part to a javascript file stored in the _layouts folder, that js file can't be found by browsers. I can't even type in the full url to download that file.

Comment: Do the files actually exist in the local file system on the server that is having the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after testing I have discovered that the minute there is a . in the folder name, SharPoint can't see the folder:

my.Folder won't work, but my_folder will work.

I have no idea why but if the only way to get all these custom solutions working again is  to replace . with _, there is a lot of reconfiguration of webparts that will need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the file exist in physical path, on a standard installation the path should be -

```
C:\Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\web server extension\12\Templates\layouts
```

Please look for your folder and file there, if they exist try to hit them from browser like - mysite/_layouts/somefolder/myfile.aspx, if you still get the error please let me know

Comment: The files do exist in the file system, as stated initially. I have deleted the folders in question in the layouts folder, and redeployed the features. This forced SharePoint to recreate the folders, and subsequently are now available to users. I will be doing more testing in the morning to confirm.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem, and it doesn't work even if i delete the folder located in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS" and re-deploy it.